# Create table from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-update

This is one annoying issue and I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

So I have two tables and I need to update both of them. They share a common key, say id. I want to update `Table1` with some stuff and then update the `Table2` rows which were respectively modified in `Table1`.

The issue is that I don't quite know which rows were modified, because I'm picking them randomly with `ORDER BY NEWID()` so I probably cannot use a `JOIN` on `Table2` in any way. I am trying to save the necessary details which were modified in my query for `Table1` and pass them to Table2

This is what I'm trying to do

```
CREATE TABLE IDS (id int not null, secondid int)

SELECT [Table1].[id], [Table1].[secondid]
INTO IDS
FROM
(
UPDATE [Table1]
SET [secondid]=100
FROM [Table1] t
WHERE t.[id] IN 
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT t.[id] FROM [Table1]
        WHERE (SOME_CONDITION)
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) 
)

UPDATE [Table2]
SET some_column=i.secondid
FROM [Table2] JOIN IDS i ON i.id = [Table2].[id]
```

But I get

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'.

So the question is: how can I solve the syntax error or is it a better way to do this?

Note: the query enclosed between the parentheses of the first `FROM` worked well before this new requirement, so I doubt there's a problem in there. Or maybe?

**EDIT**: Changing the second `UPDATE` as skk suggested still leads to the same error (on exactly the below line which contains `UPDATE`):

```
UPDATE [Table2]
SET some_column=i.secondid
FROM [Task] JOIN IDS i on i.[id]=[Table2].[id]
WHERE i.id=some_value
```

Comment: Did you try using triggers. I know it has its own performance related issues, but it might simplify the overall task.

Comment: Why would you modify rows at random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining because you aren't aliasing the derived table used in the first query, immediately preceding `UPDATE [Table2]`.

If you add an alias, you'll get a different error:

> A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause.

Which leads back to @Adam Wenger's answer.

---

Not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do, but the following sql will execute (after replacing `SOME_CONDITION`):

```
CREATE TABLE IDS (id int not null, secondid int)

UPDATE t SET [secondid] = 100
OUTPUT inserted.[id], inserted.[secondid] into [IDS]
FROM [Table1] t
WHERE t.[Id] IN
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT t.[id] from [Table1]
        WHERE (SOME_CONDITION)
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    )

UPDATE [Table2]
SET some_column = i.secondid
FROM [Table2] JOIN IDS i ON i.id = [Table2].[id]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a new table manually, SQL server has the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to help with this

Answer (score 1):

The Update syntax is as follows

```
    UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = Value WHERE {Condition}
```

but you have used FROM keyword also in that.

EDIT:

You change the code like follows and try again

```
UPDATE [Table2]  SET some_column=IDS.secondid WHERE  IDS.[id] = [Table2].[id] and 
IDS.id=some_value
```

Comment: But the UPDATE block executes fine with that FROM. I tried to remove it and I still get the same error.

Comment: If you have `FROM table1 AS t1` in your `UPDATE` statement, that works as long as you also reference the alias `UPDATE t1`

Comment: @skk Oh, I see, it was about the second UPDATE. If I add a WHERE {CONDITION} down there, I still get that error.

Comment: @skk still the same issue, it doesn't get past that UPDATE

Comment: @Kaisar, do one thing first you take aside all the queries from your big query and try out each seperately. Then you comes to know which query has mistake.