# Updating rows in a table after rows in different table were updated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, random, sql-update

This follows [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165832/create-table-from-sql-query) which was solved using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165832/create-table-from-sql-query/8166334#8166334).

Long story short: I have Table1 on which I update some random rows. Table1 and Table2 share one column (it's a foreign key). I want to update some columns from Table2, based on what was updated in Table1, but I am not sore how to let Table2 know what rows where modified in Table1.

Is there any approach *without* creating a temporary table? Like passing the modified rows from Table1 to Table2, check in Table2 for the rows matching the foreign keys of the ones which were modified and from here update these rows in Table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a table variable instead. Just replace all instances of `IDS` with `@IDS` and declare the table variable like this.

```
DECLARE @IDS TABLE (id int not null, secondid int)
```